# Can you use useCallback without assigning it to a variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, usecallback

```
// Inside a functional component.

return (
  <SomeComponent
    onClick={useCallback(() => {
      // Do something...
    }, [a, b])}
  />
);
```

I'm wondering if the code above works the same as below. Will it still memoize the function as expected?

```
const memoziedFn = useCallback(() => {
 // Do something...
}, [a, b])

return (
  <SomeComponent
    onClick={memoizedFn}
  />
);
```

Comment: It does not follow the rules of hooks, did you try it? Check out the lint error which follows.

Comment: I'm using ESlint at the moment and it does not give any warning or error. I can also run the react app with no issue. Could you maybe specify which rule of hooks it violates?

Comment: Seems something very trivial to try out. I suspect it will work, as long as you aren't conditionally rendering `SomeComponent` within the greater context of this parent component. All `useCallback` does is memoize a function in order to provide a stable reference to it. Why buck the system and established design patterns though? To save a variable declaration? Is there even an issue necessitating the use of `useCallback`?